# MySQL Push JSON object to array in database with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I want to push a new object in an existing array in the table
im thinking i can do something like this?

the object 'testJSON' is already inserted in the database, i will add it to the code below just in case

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'test'
});
connection.connect()
var sql = connection
var testJSON = [
    { "message1": {
        "replied_user": "user1",
        "replied_msg": "testing",
        "replier": "user2",
        "replier_msg": "testing again",
        "likes": "515"
        }
    },
    {"message2": {
        "replied_user": "user1",
        "replied_msg": "testing",
        "replier": "user8",
        "replier_msg": "testing again",
        "likes": "98"
        }
    },
    { "message3": {
        "replied_user": "user8",
        "replied_msg": "testing",
        "replier": "user4",
        "replier_msg": "testing again",
        "likes": "23"
        }
    }]
let xxxx = {
    'message5': {
        "replied_user": "user4",
        "replied_msg": "testing",
        "replier": "user8",
        "replier_msg": "testing again",
        "likes": "1865"
        }
}
sql.query("UPDATE users SET replies = replies += '"+JSON.stringify(xxxx)+"'", function(err, results) {
    process.exit(1)
})
```

by the query you can see what i was trying todo.

Comment: What makes you think `+=` is an operator in SQL? Did you see any documentation for this or any example code that uses `+=` in that way?

Comment: i dont, i used it as an example to show the community what im trying to todo.

Comment: pursuing this path will be very tricky: you need to somehow edit the JSON string, correctly, or you will break it. You are better downloading the entry, parse it into an array, push the new data, stringify the array & save the resulting string to the database.

Comment: why don't you use a `JSON` type field, mysql supports `JSON` fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it worked for me, hopefully it can help someone in the future

```js
sql.query("UPDATE users SET roles = COALESCE(JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(roles, '$', '"+JSON.stringify(object)+"'), JSON_ARRAY(null)) WHERE username = 'admin';")
```

Answer (score 0):

See documentation for the [JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve) function. Note you must be using MySQL 5.7.22 or later.

In your case I tested this:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( replies JSON );

INSERT INTO users SET replies = '[ ... ]'; -- your initial data for 3 messages

-- one more message for testing
-- note I changed ' to " to make it valid JSON
SET @xxx = '{
    '>     "message5": {
    '>         "replied_user": "user4",
    '>         "replied_msg": "testing",
    '>         "replier": "user8",
    '>         "replier_msg": "testing again",
    '>         "likes": "1865"
    '>         }
    '> }';

UPDATE users SET replies = JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(replies, JSON_ARRAY(CAST(@xxx AS JSON));
```

Comment: Thank you, but i've found a different solution.